# Trying to use LuaFileSystem on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: lua, ubuntu-10.04

I've installed LuaFileSystem using the command: luarocks install luafilesystem. Now I want to use it in my script but I get this error:

[splay.sandbox] W: Require of lfs refused
10:34:11.65 (6)  [splay.events] E: thread: 0x93f0b20 DIE (error: [string "job code"]:35: attempt to index local 'lfs' (a nil value))
10:34:11.65 (6)  [splay.events] E: stack traceback:
10:34:11.65 (6)     [string "job code"]:35: in function 'getHomeDirectory'
10:34:11.65 (6)     [string "job code"]:79: in function <[string "job code"]:76>

I've tried to declare it global: lfs = require"lfs", or just require"lfs", even local in a function:

```
function getHomeDirectory(position)
    local lfs = require"lfs"

    print(lfs.currentdir())
end
```

But still I get that error. There's something that I still have to do to make it work?

LATER EDIT: the same error with "a nil value" I get when trying to open a file with io:

```
local f = io.open('/home/alex/Desktop/SPLAY WORK/splay_client_commands_1.4/test1.txt', "r")
```

[splay.events] E: thread: 0x955f4c0 DIE (error: [string "job code"]:120: attempt to index local 'f' (a nil value))

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

The io.open call can be easily debugged by adding `assert` around it. This will print the error message when io.open fails to open the file:

`local f = assert(io.open('/home/alex/Desktop/SPLAY WORK/splay_client_commands_1.4/test1.txt', "r"))`

This "trick" is also described at:
http://www.lua.org/pil/21.2.html

Comment: I've done that...it says that it can open file. I've tried using restrictive io but I receive when declaring "io = require("splay.restricted_io")" the error: "Require of splay.restricted_io refused". The file exists and for restrictive io it is on the folder declared in the init function.

Comment: Sorry, can't open the file:)